# SVG object style property as javascript variable

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to do the style fill color to a javascript variable. I have to reuse this variable at different location of the SVG code.

```
<path d="......."
id="path3950" 
style="fill:#c1e0b2;"/>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Where is your javascript? Why don't you simply use CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying you have to reuse the style fill for different paths in the svg?

A javascript variable will not help you with this, what you are looking to do is use CSS class rule across multiple paths.

```
    <path d="......." class="myPaths" id="path3950"/>
    <path d="......." class="myPaths" id="path3951"/>
    <path d="......." class="myPaths" id="path3952"/>

    //in css, either by linking a file at the top of the svg
    //     or with 
    <style type="text/css" >
       <![CDATA[
            .myPaths {
                fill: #c1e0b2;
            }   
        ]]>
    </style>
```

and the CSS fill will be applied to them all.

Answer (score 1):

You can get inline css values in javascript by this code.

```
var p = document.getElementById("path3950");  
var fill_color = p.style.getPropertyValue("fill");
```

`fill_color` will be "`#c1e0b2`".